# Why do I get a seg fault when in n>500? Coded in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

in the following piece of code which I wrote for problem 28 in project Euler. It needs to add the numbers along the two diagonals of an expanding square of increasing numbers. It results in a seg fault when I set `num>500`. Until this limit it works perfectly. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int n, num=501;
  int array[num-1][num-1];
  int p=((num+1)/2)-1;
  int count=25;
  int x;

    array[p][p]=1;
    array[p+1][p]=4;
    array[p+1][p+1]=3;
    array[p][p+1]=2;
    array[p-1][p+1]=9;
    array[p-1][p]=8;
    array[p-1][p-1]=7;
    array[p][p-1]=6;
    array[p+1][p-1]=5;  

    int i=10; 
  for (n=2;((n*2)+1)<=num;n++){



    for(x=0;x<n*2;x++){
       array[p+(x-(n-1))][p+n]=i;
       i++;
    }
    count+=(i-1);



    for(x=0;x<n*2;x++){
      array[p+n][p+(n-1)-x]=i;
      i++;
    }
          count+=(i-1);




    for(x=0;x<n*2;x++){
      array[p+((n-1)-x)][p-n]=i;
      i++;
    }
     i--;


        count+=i;
    for(x=0;x<=n*2;x++){
      array[p-n][p+(x-n)]=i;
      i++;
    }

        count+=(i-1);
 }

    printf("The answer is %lu\n", count);

}
```

Comment: 500*500*4 = 1 megabyte. On some systems, that will exceed the maximum stack size. Either move the declaration of `array` outside of `main` (i.e. make it a global), or declare it with the `static` keyword, or allocate it on the heap with `malloc`.

Comment: There is a regularity in the numerical value on the diagonal do not need to use such large array.

Comment: Your code accesses out of bounds too, e.g. `p` is `250`, and when `n` is also `250` then `array[...][p+n]` is `array[...][500]` which is OOB since 500 is the array dimension

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that because `500*500*sizeof(int) == 1000000` (assuming an `sizeof (int) == 4`), you've run out of stack space.  I suggest putting it on the heap instead:

```
typedef struct { int array[num - 1][num - 1] } arr;

int main(void)
{
    const int num = 501;
    int n;
    arr *array;
    int p = (num + 1) / 2 - 1;
    int count = 25;
    int x;

    array = malloc(sizeof arr);

    array->array[p][p] = 1;
    array->array[p + 1][p] = 4;
.
.
.
```

Comment: There's no need to have `num` be global. Also, `const` variables in C aren't true constants as they are in C++, so you might want to use a symbolic constant (`#define`), but obviously that's not necessary. I've made other edits as well to make  your answer more technically correct (and slightly easier to read).

Comment: @RastaJedi `sizeof arr` is an error, the parentheses can only be omitted when the argument is an expression.  `sizeof *array` would be preferable

Comment: @M.M that was just simple oversight because the two names (arr and array) are so similar. Fixed; thank you :).